# strtotime 'this friday' and 'this sunday' not working

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for a while.

In my code I have

```
$start_date = date("Ymd", strtotime('this friday'));
$end_date = date("Ymd", strtotime('this sunday'));
```

Yesterday (Sunday) I noticed that the output wasn't correct. It seems that the PHP starts the week on Sunday? I'd like to start it on Monday. So every week, from Monday to Sunday, start_date should output the friday of this week, and end_date should output the sunday of this week (that's why I've used 'this friday' and 'this sunday').

Is this a timezone issue? If I add `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');` above the code will it fix the problem?

The thing is that I don't really know how to test this unless I wait untill it's Sunday again :-)

Comment: Define "wasn't correct" - what are you getting exactly for which date? (You can test it by forcing a timestamp as the second argument to `strtotime()`)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because I think it's easier to write an own function to get the start and enddate of the / a week..

Comment: Guess you will just have to find out the current day of the week and make adjustments to what you pass to strtotime()

Comment: @ripa Yes it is. Jack you're right, I didn't think of that and amigura answered the question this way (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

php will start from what ever date today is unless you specify, hence it started from Sunday which was yesterday.

```
if (date("w")==1){$start_monday = date("Y-m-d");}else{$start_monday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last monday'));}

$start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_monday.' this friday'));
$end_date = date("Ymd", strtotime($start_monday.' this sunday'));
```

Comment: I had the feeling it should be something simple like that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) has weeks that run from Monday to Sunday and PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes can deal with this standard.

Basically, what you need to do is to set the ISO8601 week number for the current date and set the required day, 1 - 7 for Monday - Sunday, for example:-

```
$startDate = new \DateTime();
$startDate->setISODate((int)$startDate->format('Y'), (int)$startDate->format('W'), 1);

$endDate = new \DateTime();
$endDate->setISODate((int)$startDate->format('Y'), (int)$startDate->format('W'), 5);

var_dump($startDate->format('D'));
var_dump($endDate->format('D'));
```

Output:-

```
string 'Mon' (length=3)
string 'Fri' (length=3)
```

Read the docs I linked to for more information and comment if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify 'this week' in order to make it work.

Heres an example:

`date('Ymd', strtotime('Friday this week'));`

`date('Ymd', strtotime('Sunday this week'));`